# SQL if statement returning incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement

So I have a stored procedure that is working except for how it calculates a certain field. On the tables worked with is a field called `DeliveryYearMonth` that is simply `YYYYMM` in its format. I try to compare current month info to previous month info, thus I created the following two variables.

```
DECLARE @CURDate VARCHAR(50) -- Current time (YYYYMM)
DECLARE @MAGDate VARCHAR(50) -- YearAgo Time (YYYYMM)

SET @CURDate = cast((select max(DeliveryYearMonth) from dbo.datatable) as  varchar)
SET @MAGDate = cast((substring(@CURDate,1,4)) as varchar) --For current year
         + cast((substring(@CURDate,5,2) - 1) as varchar) -- To get previous month
```

This is all fine and dandy unless the the month is January, and thus the month would become 00, and the year would stay the same.

So I tried my hand at an if statement to clear this up.

```
if(substring(@MAGDate,5,2)) = '00'-- If current Month is January
begin
Set @MAGDate = cast((substring(@CURDate,1,4) - 1) as varchar) --For previous year
         + '12' -- December
end
```

This always breaks the Month Ago Date `(@MAGDate)` even if the `IF` statement isn't true. I cannot figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: Why on Earth can't you just use a `DATE` type? I would stop everything and convert immediately.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you using `CAST` to convert strings to strings?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah, it's MS SQL Server 2008.

njk and Barmar This was crafted off of someone else's code, that's why it was string to start. I'll look into converting if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the previous version of your string, you can do the following:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(7), dateadd(month, -1, CAST(@CURDate+'01' as DATE)), 121), '-', '')
```

As a comment suggested, though, you should really just store this as a date, assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or more recent.

Comment: Did the second part. Thanks.